# Change iframe source from another iframe when both the iframe are in same page

Tags: php, html, iframe, audio-player

I have this following code where i cannot play the player in second iframe from first iframe . Although this works fine if the link to play song is in the main page and not inside the first iframe

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function music(dir) {
          alert(dir);
        var iframe = document.getElementById("player");
        iframe.src = dir;
      } 
</script>

<iframe src="home.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" style="background:#993333"></iframe>

<iframe id="player" src="player.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="400px" height="100px" style="background:#66FF99"></iframe>
```

//home.php

```
<a href="#" onclick="return music('player.php?item=test2')" >Song2</a>
```

//player.php

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="dewplayer.swf?mp3=mp3/music.mp3&amp;autostart=1" width="200" height="20" id="dewplayer"><param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:
main.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function music(dir) {
          alert(dir);
        var iframe = document.getElementById("player");
        iframe.src = dir;
      } 
</script>
<iframe src="home.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" style="background:#993333"></iframe>

<iframe id="player" src="player.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="400px" height="100px" style="background:#66FF99"></iframe>
```

player.php

```
<?php if(!empty($_GET['item'])){echo '<div>item = '.$_GET['item'].'</div>';} ?>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="dewplayer.swf?mp3=mp3/music.mp3&amp;autostart=1" width="200" height="20" id="dewplayer"><param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```

home.php

```
<a href="#" onclick="parent.music('player.php?item=test2')" >Song2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First iframe doesn't have an ID.
2. Both those iframes are not part of each other's `document`. So if you have to change url of one from the other you have to bring in `parent` in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new `window.postMessage` API to send a message from one remote frame to it's parent, and then have the parent window proxy that make message back to the other iframe by passing that message onto the other iframe.

For documentation on this, see the Mozilla page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage)